# Cascading functions in Python using reduce and decorators

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-decorators, method-resolution-order

I have a method called `render` that is actually implemented by a subclass and called like this:

```
class MyClass(object):

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        api_response = self.render(*args, **kwargs)

        return api_response

    def render(self, *args, **kwargs):
        """ This method is implemented by a subclass."""    
        raise NotImplementedError

    def cascade_callables():
        print 'Ask awesome people at stackoverflow for the solution to this problem.'
```

I have a list of callables `[c1, c2, c3]`. I want to do something like this inside the `cascade_callables` method which should be something like this:

```
def cascade_callables():
    callables = [c1, c2, c3]
    callables.append(self.render)
    self.render = reduce(some_decorator_that_accepts_two_functions, callables)
```

So essentially, I am trying my `render` to work like this without modifying the actual implementation:

```
c1(*args, **kwargs)
c2(*args, **kwargs)
c3(*args, **kwargs)
render(*args, **kwargs)
```

I tried something like this to work as the decorator for me that I can use in `reduce`:

```
def cascade_modifiers(modifier1, modifier2):

    def cascaded_modifier(self, *args, **kwargs):

        modifier1(self, *args, **kwargs)
        modifier2(self, *args, **kwargs)

    return cascaded_modifier
```

But I got this:

```
TypeError: cascaded_modifier() takes at least 1 argument (0 given)
```

What is the best approach to solve this problem in Python 2.7 using the paradigm that I have tried explaining in this question?

Comment: ...Why are you doing this? Is there not a simpler way? Instead of mutating `self.render` in order to butt infront of a subclass (which is a *really* bad idea for extensibility), can't you just make subclasses implement, say `_render` which is called by a `render` that they don't overload? Or can't you implement `superrender` and call that instead of `render`? Can't you subclass their `MyClass` subclass with a sub-subclass and overload the behaviour there? What you're doing seems like a last resort to me.

Answer (score 2):

The trouble you're having is that you're saving your new `render` method in an instance variable. That means it won't get `self` passed to it automatically, as Python's method binding uses the descriptor protocol, and descriptors only work if they are class variables.

So, you probably need to make sure all your callables are already bound (if they need to use `self`) and to rewrite `cascaded_modifier` to not expect a `self` parameter. You actually already were passing a bound version of the original `render` function, so it's actually good in that case that you weren't going to get a second copy of `self`!

Note that can simplify `cascade_callables` if you use a loop rather than `reduce`. This approach requires one fewer function:

```
def cascade_callables(self):
    callables = [c1, c2, c3]   # these should be bound methods if they need self
    callables.append(self.render)

    def new_render(*args, **kwargs): # no self parameter here
        for c in callables:
            c(*args, **kwargs)       # nor here

    self.render = new_render
```

If for some reason you did need to pass `self` to the callables, and there was not a practical way to make them bound methods, you could do things a bit differently and use the `self` parameter from the enclosing `cascade_callables` scope:

```
def cascade_callables(self):
    callables = [c1, c2, c3]   # if these are not bound, we can work around the issue
    old_render = self.render   # this one is bound though so we can't mix it in

    def new_render(*args, **kwargs): # no self parameter here
        for c in callables:
            c(self, *args, **kwargs) # but here we access the enclosing scope's self
        old_render(*args, **kwargs)  # this needs to be called separately in this version

    self.render = new_render
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not make the subclass implement a different method, `_render`? Then `render` can be

```
def render(self, *args, **kwargs):
    for func in [c1, c2, c3, self._render]:
        func(*args, **kwargs)
```

That seems simpler.

Answer (score -1):

Lets forget about the fact that you are dealing with Class methods for a moment and talk about the jist of what you are trying to do.

First, you have something like

```
c1(*args, **kwargs)
c2(*args, **kwargs)
c3(*args, **kwargs)
render(*args, **kwargs) # <- the decorator should not be placed here

@render(*args, **kwargs) # <- it should be placed here
c1(*args, **kwargs)
c2(*args, **kwargs)
c3(*args, **kwargs)
```

What you want is that the above should translate to

```
@renderc1(*args, **kwargs)
c2(*args, **kwargs)
c3(*args, **kwargs)
```

then to

```
@renderc1c2(*args, **kwargs)
c3(*args, **kwargs)
```

and then to

```
@renderc1c2(*args, **kwargs)
c3(*args, **kwargs)
```

Remember that the @ operator is just syntactic sugar for

```
@render(*args, **kwargs) # <- it should be placed here
c1(*args, **kwargs)
```

becomes:

Now lets put the other functions in

```
@render(*args, **kwargs) # <- it should be placed here
c1(*args, **kwargs)
c2(*args, **kwargs)
c3(*args, **kwargs)
```

becomes

```
c1 = render(c1)
c2(*args, **kwargs)
c3(*args, **kwargs)
```

which is meaningless.

What you want is:

```
@render(*args, **kwargs) # <- it should be placed here
c1(*args, **kwargs)
@c1
c2(*args, **kwargs)
@c2
c3(*args, **kwargs)
```

which losely translates to:

```
c1 = render(c1)
c2 = c1(c2)
c3 = c2(c3)
```

etc.

Where, the previous function makes the next function a decorator. The question is, how do you stop the last function from becoming a decorator?
If there was some sort if *ID* function, this might be possible (something like monad transforers in Haskell). But not really sure how to achieve this.

Comment: I think you're interpreting "decorator" too literally. The questioner isn't using Python's decorator syntax anywhere. What I think "decorator" means in this context is just a function that works on (and returns) other functions.

Answer (score -2):

Your cascade_modifier expects self as first parameter. Why do You need it?
You decorator doesn't receives function object, which You need actually to decorate.
And main thing - reduce already sort of decorator in terms that it accepts function, changes its behavior and returns new function. So, You don't need to bother about decorator to pass to reduce. Just use regular function.

Comment: "Your cascade_modifier expects self as first parameter. Why do You need it?" - because it's an instance method, and instance methods need to declare a `self` argument, and the argument is actually used, so making it a module-level function won't remove the requirement for that parameter. Also, `reduce` isn't a decorator and doesn't build a new function from the reduction function supplied. (That said, looking for a decorator to pass to `reduce` instead of other kinds of functions isn't a great idea.)